# Exportar tabla de databricks hacia sql server en azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql, spark

Estoy intentando LLevar la tabla "tabla_DB" que esta dentro de Databricks hacia  SQL server dentro del entorno de AZURE, pero al parecer no reconoce mis comandos, he ido probando con estos comandos y nada

La primera forma:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
import pandas as pd

jdbcHostname = "MISERVIDOR.database.windows.net" 
jdbcPort = 1433
jdbcDatabase = "DATA1" 
jdbcUsername = "YOMISMO"
jdbcPassword = "123456"
jdbcDriver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{jdbcHostname}:{jdbcPort};databaseName={jdbcDatabase};user={jdbcUsername}:password={jdbcPassword}"

tabla_DB = DataFrameWriter(tabla_DB)
tabla_DB.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table="tabla_SQL", mode = "overwrite")

NameError: name 'tabla_DB' is not defined
```

La segunda forma:

```
arrtime.write \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://MISERVIDOR.database.windows.net:1433;database=MIDATABASE") \
    .option("tabla_SQL", "tabla_DB") \ 
    .option("user", "YOMISMO") \
    .option("password", "123456") \
    .save()

NameError: name 'tabla_SQL' is not defined
```

Comment: De casualidad en tu segunda opción tienes un typo en `.option("tabla_SQL", "tabla_SQL")`, y más bien debería ser algo como, `.option("dbtable", "tabla_SQL")`?

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que (si escribiste todo en tu publicación como lo estás utilizando), tienes  varios errores como:

En la línea que contiene `tabla_DB = DataFrameWriter(tabla_DB)`, en ninguna parte de lo que mostraste defines la variable, `tabla_DB`.

En la segunda forma, cuando utilizás, `.option("tabla_SQL", "tabla_DB")`, me parece que, siguiendo la [documentación](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html), debería usar algo como `.option("dbtable", "tabla_DB")`.